# Unable to view the contents of the object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, object, console.log

Trying to execute the following piece of code -

```
 <script>
      var Person = function(name, age, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
      };

      var person = new Person(“fred”, 30, “fred@gmail.com”);
      for (var prop in person)
        console.log(prop + “ = “+person[prop]);
    </script>
```

Expected Output:

```
name = fred
age = 30
email = fred@gmail.com
```

Link to the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/raina140291/mw2c704d/

I already installed the external script to view the contents of the console, but it doesn't display anything for the above code.

Fairly new to java script, would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: your fiddle is wrong, some code in it does not make sense. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? So that we can understand the code.

Comment: @RobG - you're right, I removed the tag

Comment: Change your double quotes to single quote. like var person = new Person('fred', 30, 'fred@gmail.com');

Comment: Use the correct quote character, either plain " or '.

Comment: @Reddy - Added the expected output

Comment: yes the quotes was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only issue was with this `“fred”, 30, “fred@gmail.com”` its not same as `"fred", 30, "fred@gmail.com"` or `'fred', 30, 'fred@gmail.com'`. Change it and everything seems fine.

```js
var Person = function(name, age, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
  };

  var person = new Person('fred', 30, 'fred@gmail.com');
  for (var prop in person)
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += prop + ' = '+person[prop] + '<br/>';
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have copy and pasted this from somewhere as the only problem is that you have the wrong kind of quotes. Compare:

```
“fred”
```

should be

`"fred"` or `'fred'`